# How can I parse the strange type of JSON?

Tags: php, json, regex, parsing

I have a string content like [this](http://pastebin.com/2i5M6JZs). As far as I know it is JSON. Because it is the response of an ajax request. Now I need to parse it, how can I do that?

Noted that I can do that by *regex*, but as you know, doing that is highly non-recommended.

Comment: what you have pasted in not valid JSON.

Comment: the code after 86103 is array

Comment: Figure it out on http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: Looks like you are working with a feed from gmail or similar which is JSON in format but mostly array based. You need the encoding details so the you can make sense of this. Otherwise you are going nowhere unless the API has published documentation for the message formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON data you have provided  is pretty invalid. You will need to fix that first then you can convert it to php arrays using native functions.

Feeding this JSON to a (Standard) parser in almost any language will give you error. The reason is that these parsers are based on predefined rules for the JSON format. So, I will suggest to work on the source of data and make it a valid JSON.

If you still insist to use that data for the parser then you need to find a "forgiving" parser. The [PHP native JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php) extension cannot be beaten for speed, but it is very unforgiving on the json it parses as valid. And its sure hit for almost everybody.

[PEAR JSON](https://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON) is a forgiving parser which will parse and reformat invalid JSON for you, You will need to install that extension. But I will still recommend working with valid data because mal-formed JSON can result in unpredictable results and you will not like that in production.